# couchbase view query group by parts of key

Tags: javascript, database, view, couchbase

I've got some data that contains messages including:

```
mac
version
source
timestamp
```

I want to know how many devices were on which version last week. For example,

```
version 1.0: 20
version 2.1: 45
version 3.4: 3198
```

So say my view is as follows:

```
map: function (doc, meta) {
  emit([doc.timestamp, doc.source, doc.mac, doc.version], 1);
}
```

How would I group by mac and version?

I can use the timestamp to control the range of message I'm looking at. But the problem is I only care about the number of devices, not the number of messages. A group by that includes the timestamp includes every message from the devices, but I'm only concerned with the number of devices and their version, not the count of messages.

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using? Is N1QL out of the question (and why)?

Comment: I'm on Enterprise Edition 5.1.0 build 5552. I'm new to databases in general. Isn't couchbase's strength in views and the performance of having data indexed ahead of time? N1QL is incredibly slow for me

Comment: What index are you using for the N1QL query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from a M/R expert, but would this work:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit([doc.version, doc.timestamp, doc.source, doc.mac], 1);
}
```

For startkey: `["0","2018-05-06"]`
For endkey: `["Z","2018-05-13"]`

This means, every document with a version that falls between 0 and Z (which should be everything) and every document with a timestamp between two given dates.

For group_level: `1` (grouping by the version)

For reduce, use built in `_count`

I tested this with 4 documents (2 in version 1.0 and 2 in version 2.1) and it seemed to work:

[image]

Comment: That sounds very much like what I'm looking for, basically a way to set a wild card for one part of the key. Unfortunately that doesn't work. Because key ranges are ordered, the start key and end key you provided will select EVERYTHING and the timestamp will not have an effect of filtering by date